# Publishing table back to tickerplant

Tags: kdb

I am trying to publish a table straight from a real time engine. Basically I have a real time engine that connects to the tickerplant, subscribes to a raw version of a table and adds some new columns. Now I want this enhanced version of the table to be pushed back to the tickerplant. I have a pub function which pushes the table in the follwoing way:

```
neg[handle](`.u.upd;`tablename;tabledata)
```

the problem is that I get a type error. I looked at the schemas of the table and they are slightly different.

```
meta table1
c               | t f a
----------------| -----
time            | p
sym             | s
col1            | c
col2            | s
col3            | i

meta table2
c               | t f a
----------------| -----
time            | p
sym             | s
col1            | C
col2            | s
col3            | i
```

That capital `C` most likely is the problem. However, I cannot load the schema in the tickerplant with capital letters. Any idea how should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the schema with a generic list type and it will take its type from the first insert.

```
tab:([] col1:`int$();generic:();col3:`$())
```

Another issue is that your tickerplant might be expecting a list (of lists) to be sent to its .u.upd rather than the table you may be sending to it, so you may want to `value flip` your table before sending it. (And note that the tickerplant would try to prepend a timestamp if the first column isn't already a timestamp)

Answer (score 1):

The capital C in your meta table is the result of the incoming data being nested. To resolve this you should declare the schema with an untyped empty list.

```
table2:([] time:`timestamp$();sym:`$();col1:();col2:`$();col3:"I"$())
```

Consequently, until a result is entered its meta is:

```
q)meta table2
c   | t f a
----| -----
time| p
sym | s
col1|
col2| s
col3| i
```

This will then be updated to match the first entry into the table.

Also, .u.upd requires the input to not be a table but a list of lists, this can be resolved 
 using:

```
neg[handle](`.u.upd;`tablename;value flip tabledata)
```

Comment: hey thanks! That's what I was looking for. However, unless I am losing data at the moment, the `value flip tabledata` is not necessary. In fact it doesn't even work. I think our upd function is equipped to deal with type 98 coming through the handle.